# Is it possible to repair a Cisco 3500 XL (3548) switch with POST Error messages?

Tags: cisco, switch

I've got an old Cisco 3500 XL, and it seems to have hardware issues. I've loaded the latest IOS and cleared all config.

Does anyone have any experience fixing the switch core? I'm a reasonably competent SMD solderer, can I replace/reflow some chips?

I've checked the power supply voltages and it's all within tolerance, and no visible signs of any component damage. Some chips are hot to the touch.

I understand that these were EOL as of 2007, but should have a lifetime warranty for the electronics. I don't have a Cisco support contract, so I can't file a ticket. What should I do?

Console output:

```
switch: dir flash:
Directory of flash:/

2    -rwx  1811584   <date>               c3500xl-c3h2s-mz.120-5.WC17.bin

1799680 bytes available (1812992 bytes used)
switch: boot
Loading "flash:c3500xl-c3h2s-mz.120-5.WC17.bin"...###################################################################################################################################################################################

File "flash:c3500xl-c3h2s-mz.120-5.WC17.bin" uncompressed and installed, entry point: 0x3000
executing...

              Restricted Rights Legend

Use, duplication, or disclosure by the Government is
subject to restrictions as set forth in subparagraph
(c) of the Commercial Computer Software - Restricted
Rights clause at FAR sec. 52.227-19 and subparagraph
(c) (1) (ii) of the Rights in Technical Data and Computer
Software clause at DFARS sec. 252.227-7013.

           cisco Systems, Inc.
           170 West Tasman Drive
           San Jose, California 95134-1706



Cisco Internetwork Operating System Software
IOS (tm) C3500XL Software (C3500XL-C3H2S-M), Version 12.0(5)WC17, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Copyright (c) 1986-2007 by cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Tue 13-Feb-07 15:04 by antonino
Image text-base: 0x00003000, data-base: 0x00352924


Initializing C3500XL flash...
flashfs[1]: 1 files, 1 directories
flashfs[1]: 0 orphaned files, 0 orphaned directories
flashfs[1]: Total bytes: 3612672
flashfs[1]: Bytes used: 1812992
flashfs[1]: Bytes available: 1799680
flashfs[1]: flashfs fsck took 3 seconds.
flashfs[1]: Initialization complete.
...done Initializing C3500XL flash.
C3500XL POST: System Board Test: Passed
C3500XL POST: Daughter Card Test: Passed
C3500XL POST: CPU Buffer Test: Passed
C3500XL POST: CPU Notify RAM Test: Passed
C3500XL POST: CPU Interface Test: Passed
C3500XL POST: Testing Switch Core: Passed
Error with Switch Core BIST test Phase 0.
Returns: Test Complete Low : 0x0FFFFFFF, Test Complete High  : 0xFFFFFFFE
         Test Phase Low    : 0x00000040, Test Phase High     : 0x00000000
         Test Phase Third  : 0x00000000, Test Complete Third : 0x000001F8

C3500XL POST FAILURE: Testing Switch Core: Failed
C3500XL POST FAILURE: Testing Buffer Table: Failed
C3500XL POST FAILURE: Data Buffer Test: Failed
C3500XL POST FAILURE: Configuring Switch Parameters: Failed
C3500XL POST FAILURE: Switch Core BIST failed.
C3500XL POST FAILURE: Cannot test Modules due to failure of Switch Core POST
Del Mar Failure (0th Del Mar): req system failed to init
C3500XL POST FAILURE:
C3500XL POST FAILURE: ATM: required system failed to init
C3500XL POST: Ethernet Controller Test: Passed
C3500XL POST FAILURE: MII Test: Failed
C3500XL POST FAILURE: Error waiting for Ethernet Controller and SW_PARAMS
C3500XL POST FAILURE: Initialization/POST failed
C3500XL POST FAILURE: AT: Failing because system POST failed
Exception (8192)! Debug Exception (Could be NULL pointer dereference)
CPU Register Context:
Vector = 0x00002000  PC = 0x000F36F4  MSR = 0x00029200  CR = 0x22000024
LR = 0x000F6964  CTR = 0x001DE46C  XER = 0x00000000
R0 = 0x00000000  R1 = 0x004E2580  R2 = 0x00000000  R3 = 0x00000000
R4 = 0x00000001  R5 = 0x00000000  R6 = 0x004E2718  R7 = 0x004E2718
R8 = 0x00000008  R9 = 0x00000000  R10 = 0x0000FFFF  R11 = 0x00480000
R12 = 0x42000024  R13 = 0x00000000  R14 = 0x00000000  R15 = 0x00000000
R16 = 0x00000000  R17 = 0x00000000  R18 = 0x00000000  R19 = 0x00000000
R20 = 0x00000000  R21 = 0x00000000  R22 = 0x00000000  R23 = 0x00000000
R24 = 0x00000000  R25 = 0x00000020  R26 = 0x004E2718  R27 = 0x004E2718
R28 = 0x00000020  R29 = 0x00002513  R30 = 0x00000001  R31 = 0x00000000

Stack trace:
PC = 0x000F36F4, SP = 0x004E2580
Frame 00: SP = 0x004E25A0    PC = 0x40000016
Frame 01: SP = 0x004E2618    PC = 0x000F6964
Frame 02: SP = 0x004E26A8    PC = 0x000F76DC
Frame 03: SP = 0x004E26C8    PC = 0x000E8114
Frame 04: SP = 0x004E26F0    PC = 0x001F5BF8
Frame 05: SP = 0x004E2710    PC = 0x001F5CF4
Frame 06: SP = 0x004E2748    PC = 0x0023F4DC
Frame 07: SP = 0x004E2750    PC = 0x0023E650
Frame 08: SP = 0x004E27C8    PC = 0x0023E89C
Frame 09: SP = 0x004E27E0    PC = 0x0028AF34
Frame 10: SP = 0x004E27E8    PC = 0x001E38F8
Frame 11: SP = 0x004E2808    PC = 0x001E39A8
Frame 12: SP = 0x004E2820    PC = 0x0014E220
Frame 13: SP = 0x004E28C8    PC = 0x0014E39C
Frame 14: SP = 0x00000000    PC = 0x001EB510
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't bother.

You can pick up a second hand switch, even refurbished with limited warranty, for next to nothing on various online market-places.

Ebay has them for around $75. Why bother repairing. Your time alone is probably more valuable.